# Maximum value of $f(x) = \log_{(\tan x + \cot x)}(\det A)$ for a diagonal matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functions, determinant

If $$A =\begin{pmatrix}
        d_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & d_2 & 0 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & d_3 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 0 & d_4\\
        \end{pmatrix}$$ where $d_i>0$ $\forall$ $i=1,2,3,4$ is a **diagonal matrix** of order **4**

such that $d_1+2d_2+4d_3+8d_4=16$ then the maximum value of $f(x)=\log_{(\tan x+\cot x)}(\det(A))$ where $x \in (0,\pi/2)$ is equal to

---

**My attempt at the solution-**

I have no idea how to approach this one. All I did was calculated the $|A|$, which came out to be $d_1 d_2 d_3 d_4$ . I further calculated the minimum value of $\tan x+\cot x$ by expressing it in form of $\sin(2x)$. The minimum value comes out to be **2** (at $x=\pi/2$)

So I am now left with the expression $\log_2 d_1 d_2 d_3 d_4$ and cannot move further. I have no idea how to use the given equation in the solution.

The answer comes out to be equal to $2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hint: Use AM-GM inequality
$$d_{1}+2d_{2}+4d_{3}+8d_{4}\ge 4\sqrt[4]{2^2\cdot 2^3\cdot 2 d_{1}d_{2}d_{3}d_{4}}=8\sqrt{2}\cdot\sqrt[4]{\det{(A)}}$$
so
$$\det{(A)}\le 4$$
and since
$$\tan{x}+\cot{x}\ge 2$$
so
$$f(x)\le log_{2}{4}=2$$